# Android Firebase upload image not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

I am trying to use the following code to have a user select an image, and after the image is selected, it is automatically uploaded to my Firebase storage. I initialized the variable storageReference in the OnCreate function

```
    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext());
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), 2);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

```
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // If the image is uploaded properly and the resultcode is OK
        // The imagePreview is updated and the image is uploaded
        if(requestCode == 1 || requestCode == 2) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() == null) {
                filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(requireContext().getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    imagePreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    uploadImage();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    private void uploadImage()
    {
        if (filePath != null) {

            // Code for showing progressDialog while uploading
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            // Defining the child of storageReference
            StorageReference ref = storageReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().toString());

            // adding listeners on upload
            // or failure of image
            ref.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // Image uploaded successfully
                            // Dismiss dialog
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Uploaded!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            // Error, Image not uploaded
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Failed " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                // Progress Listener for loading
                                // percentage on the dialog box
                                @Override
                                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                    double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                                    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int)progress + "%");
                                }
                    });
        }
    }
```

My guess is that the uploadImage function is not being called but I am not sure why.

Comment: so what happens when you debug it with breakpoints ? have you tried doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the issue was with this line

`if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() == null)`

`data.getData() == null`

should be:

`data.getData() != null`